# twice loading image and flickering site with angular ssr 9

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have two problem with my project in angular ssr 9:
1-twice loading images in carousel.
[image]

2-flickering header in load first time.
[image]

I tried very hard to find a cause but couldn't.
[source of my project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1njCJ84JQA7frEQrP9VONEFlIBS0P9BbN/view?usp=sharing).
If anyone can find a cause, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

About the flickering problem, [this thread](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1184) will help.

It has tips on how to achieve a smoother transition from server app to client app.

Try adding `TransferHttpCacheModule` in app.module.ts.

About the twice loading images in carousel, looks like it has to do with the lazyload you are using. For src works fine.

Comment: not resolve problem with adding TransferHttpCacheModule in app.module.ts